Poner los componentes de Devexpress en español
En la version 21.2.4 del devexpress veo que no es necesario, los Objetos del devexpress ya aparecen en español pero de ahi en adelante, como ejemplo el 23.1 y 24.1 no he logrado poder ponerlos en español, solo lo logro a nivel de desarrollo pero al momento de distribución no ,lo logro, utilizo VB net 2022.
seleos agradeceria si cme pueden colaborar con esto, he visto videos de yotubi, pero solo con versiones mucho mas antigua.
Muchas gracias.

preguntarles a ellos no es una opcion?
